# Is there any way to Connect Raspi to devops for CD/CI pipeline?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, raspberry-pi4

I have used tfs agent to communicate dev,test & prod in which i pushed the code using the agents. Is there any other way to do the same as RASPI 4 is not supporting TFS Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hosted agent to run a custom script if your PI was had a publicly accessible address. FTP is also an option depending on what you need your deployment to do. Make sure you take care of your secrets(SSH key, passwords) and properly secure your PI if you make it publically addressable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops

Another option would be to make a custom script that runs on the PI and pulls down data from Azure Dev Ops using the CLI or Web API. It wouldn't be fancy but your PI wouldn't need to be publically addressable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops

Comment: Sending via SSH is not possible as it (SSH) is restricted in a organisation network. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can try FTP if isn't restricted. If you can't have DevOps connect into the target machine, you will have to have the target machine poll dev ops on a interval.

Comment: Can you share any blog or something regarding the above answer as i am a beginner and i didn't understand fully or maybe a detailed answer if possible.

Comment: Sorry, don't have a blog post or anything handy. You would have to make a custom script/app and use the Azure DevOps Restful API linked above. It would be a significate amount of work.